# Call to a member function notify() on integer in LARAVEL 5.8

Tags: laravel, notifications

I am working on a task schedule. The flow is I need to send notification as a reminder for their duedate.

here's my **console\command\remindDuedate**

```
class remindDuedate extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'remindDuedate:run';   
    protected $description = 'Command description';    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }    
    public function handle()
    {
        while (true) {
            $loanapplications = LoanApplication::where('archive',false)->where('status','=',2)->get();          

            foreach ($loanapplications as $application) {

                $user = $application->user_id;

                $date_approval = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($application->date_approval));

                $duration = $application->loanDuration->num_days;
                $duedate_warning = $duration-3;

                $reminder_date = $date_approval->addDays($duedate_warning)->toDateString();

                $now = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->toDateString();
                $duedate = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila')->addDays(3)->toDateString();

                if($reminder_date == $now) {

                    $user->notify(new remindDuedateNotif());
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

**php artisan remindDuedate:run**

[image]

**remindDuedateNotif**

[image]

Why do I getting the "Call to a member function notify() on integer"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: because a `user_id` attribute is an integer, not a user object, `$user = $application->user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching the user, therefor the user is still an integer, set it like so.

```
$user = User::find($application->user_id);
```

**EDIT**

As you can see your notification takes a user as the first argument. Therefor send it with it.

```
$user->notify(new remindDuedateNotif($user));
```

This is weird to send and notify on the User object and pass it. You are in luck as every `$notifiable` parameter is actually an user, as it would be the object you send it from.

So remove $user from `__contruct()` and everywhere you access the user, you can do the following.

```
'user_id' => $notifiable->id,
```

Comment: i guess the error fixed but new one came out. new error says, "   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Too few arguments to function App\Notifications\remindDuedateNotif::__construct(), 0
passed in E:\wamp64\www\aftscredit-appzcoder\app\Console\Commands\remindDuedate.php on line 66 and exactly 1 expected" . the line 19 is pointing to public function __construct($user). please refer to my notification screenshot "remindDuedateNotif"

Comment: thank you for updating your answer. I already applied it. and also I removed the $user form public function __construct(). shall I remove the "$this->user = $user;
" inside it? because after I remove the $user i got "Undefined variable: user"

Comment: change all $user to $notifiable

Answer (score 0):

1) the User Model should have the notifiable trait

Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable

2) you need to add a relation between the application and user in thee application model

```
   public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

3) notify the application user :

```
$application->user->notify(new remindDuedateNotif());
```

Comment: hi I already have notifiable on my user model and it is already have working relationship between application and user